# Parsing a txt file using open csv

Tags: java, parsing, opencsv

Can anybody tell me how can i parse the file using open csv? I am trying from many days but i didnt get a result. Here is my code

```
package csv;

import java.io.IOException;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import csv.*;
import java.io.*;
public class CSVParser {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,java.io.FileNotFoundException   {

 try{ 
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("D:\\error.txt"));

     String sLine = null;

     String[] nextLine;

     int count=0,flag=0;
     nextLine=reader.readNext();
     while( (nextLine!=null)  )  
        {
            count++;
            System.out.println("count::: "+count + "and length is" +nextLine.length);
            System.out.println("String:::"+nextLine[0]);
            if ( (nextLine.length!= 9)   ) {

               flag=1;
                break;
            }

            nextLine=reader.readNext();
        }
    System.out.println("No of lines:::"+count);


    if(flag==1)
        {
                reader.close();
                System.out.println("errror");
                movefiles m= new movefiles();
                m.move("D:\\error.txt");
        }

    else{

                System.out.println("No error");

            try{
           while((nextLine=reader.readNext())!=null)      {
          String   code                = nextLine[0].toString();
          String   commodity           = nextLine[1].toString();
          float          contract_price      = Float.parseFloat(nextLine[2].toString());
          float          open_contract_vol   = Float.parseFloat(nextLine[3].toString());
          float          open_contract_price = Float.parseFloat(nextLine[4].toString());
          float          unpriced_vol        = Float.parseFloat(nextLine[5].toString());
          float          holdover_prod       = Float.parseFloat(nextLine[6].toString());
          String          date                = nextLine[7].toString();
          String          time                = nextLine[8].toString();
          System.out.println("Data From File is :::" + code +commodity +contract_price +open_contract_vol +open_contract_price +unpriced_vol +holdover_prod +date +time);
            }}catch(Exception e)

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("here is error:::"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    reader.close();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("error:::" +e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

But problem is when i run this code even if  my file contains one line it shows two lines and second line doesn't contain anything. I think it may contain white space. can anybody tell me why even if my file contain one line it is showing me 2 and how can i overcome it. How to read a single line at a time. pls help me i am new to csv for this i am using opencsv jar library

Comment: Did you manually type this code into the question (its not compilable)? I see at least two problems in your code but will not mention them because it may be typos when you transcribed the question.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience.   i have edited my code. I have uploaded whole code can you please have look at it

Comment: Please run `find /c /v "~`!@#$%^&*()_+" error.txt` in your windows. Show us the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your input file its hard to tell. But in any case the first part of your code works as it should, iterating over the lines in the input file. But the second part of your code is questionable:

```
if(flag==1) {
    reader.close();
    System.out.println("errror");
    movefiles m= new movefiles();
    m.move("D:\\error.txt");
} else{
    // ...
}
```

The else check is unnecessary, if there was no error on any of the lines (column count less than 9), then the first part of the code would have already iterated to the end of the file. You either want to:

- Move the parsing of the row data into the first while loop.
- Store each String[] array in a list, so that you can iterate over it
  later

Create a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) with your input file so we can verify there are no errors in it.